# How to rank in just a few lines

Tags: sql, oracle, dense-rank

> Blockquote

I have 1 data table as follows:

```
CAR TIME
C0  9/20/2021 9:28:08 AM
B5  9/20/2021 10:27:24 AM
D2  9/20/2021 7:27:07 AM
C14 9/20/2021 8:12:48 AM
H6  9/20/2021 9:41:18 AM
G1  9/20/2021 9:22:56 AM
G1  9/20/2021 9:22:56 AM
H1  9/20/2021 9:22:56 AM
B10 9/20/2021 1:50:31 AM
A12 9/20/2021 1:50:31 AM
A12 9/20/2021 1:50:31 AM
B12 9/20/2021 1:50:31 AM
B11 9/20/2021 1:50:31 AM
A10 9/20/2021 1:50:31 AM
D10 9/20/2021 1:50:31 AM
B8  9/19/2021 11:57:46 AM
H3  9/19/2021 2:50:50 PM
D6  9/20/2021 2:10:45 AM
A1  9/20/2021 2:58:09 AM
D7  9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
D11 9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
D12 9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
E4  9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
D9  9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
D14 9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
D8  9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
D4  9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
D2  9/19/2021 6:49:30 PM
```

if i want to get 3 lines before and 4 lines after A1 and A10 how to do in sql oracle. I'm using DENSE_RANK but I can only rank all the lines but not what I want. please help me

my friend uses spotfire software this way

> Max([column1]) over (Intersect(LastPeriods(11,[column
> Rank]),[column2]))

because this way can work on large amount of data.
I want to do it on oracle sql, is it possible?

Comment: The question, given your sample data, makes no sense. The "times" are not unique. `A10` appears on the same date and at the same time with several other rows. Which of those are "before" `A10` and which are "after"? (I assume by "lines" you mean "rows"; text has lines, tables have rows, and since text can be stored in tables, the distinction is not just academic.)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . you can use count(*) as a window function.  The idea is to count how many matches appear in the 3 rows following a given row (for the "3 rows before") or in the 4 rows preceding a given row (for the "4 rows after):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(case when car in ('A1', 'A10') then 1 else 0 end) over
                   (order by time
                    rows between current row and 3 following
                   ) as cnt_following,
             count(case when car in ('A1', 'A10') then 1 else 0 end) over
                   (order by time
                    rows between 4 preceding and current row
                   ) as cnt_preceding
      from t
     )
where cnt_following > 0 or cnt_preceding > 0;
```

Comment: If I have a larger amount of data than I want my car list to be 1000 lines (A1,A2,A3...A1000), then this method cannot be used.

Comment: @levi_ackerman - why can't this method be used? If you have 10 million rows then perhaps it will take longer (still seconds, perhaps a few minutes), but it definitely can be used.

Comment: @gordonlinoff - why not simply count in the window `rows between 4 preceding and 3 following`?

Comment: how can i fill in car in ('A1', 'A2',A3,...A1000)

Comment: @mathguy . . . I think that would also work, but because the numbers are different, I just viewed the two windows separately.  It actually seems strange that the look back and look ahead windows are different.

Comment: @levi_ackerman . . . You would just adjust the `IN` list.